# Как заставить Ant компилировать пропуская классы с ошибками?

Tags: java, ant

Есть простенький **java** проект...
Некоторые файлы(в разных пакетах), имеют ошибки синтаксиса.
Как сделать так, чтобы при компиляции **Apache ANT** пропускал файлы, в которых ошибки есть, и компилировал все  которые сможет.

Сейчас  **Apache ANT** спотыкается на первой же ошибке синтаксиса...

**Как заставить Ant  компилировать пропуская файлы с ошибками?**

*(классы в основном не зависят друг от друга)*

**ant_build.xml:**

```
<project name="prg" default="compile" basedir=".">
<property name="prgName" value="prg"/>

<property name="src"   location="src"/>
<property name="build" location=".build"/>
<target name="compile">

    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src}"
           destdir="${build}"
    />
</target>  
</project>
```

При попытке выполнить target **compile** появляется ошибка:

```
D:\...\ant_build.xml:17: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Это как вы себе представляете? Так не получится

Comment: Т.е. ты хочешь, чтобы если в классе ошибка, то он не попадал в war file? А потом когда надо будет вызывать этот класс/ методы из него, что будет происходить?

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov... НЕТ(извините, что запутал сборкой в war).  Я поправил текст ant_build.xml... надо  просто скомпилировать кучу **.java** файлов из одной папки в кучу **.class** файлов, в другую папку. НО если один из кучи java файлов не компилируется, то не останавливать компиляцию всех остальных, а просто пропустить тот с которым проблема.

Comment: Просто я совсем не понимаю, зачем тебе нужны не валидные class файлы

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov... они будут очень даже валидные (те, которые соберуться). Те, что не соберуться - не важны, их потом удалят.

Comment: Ну тогда исключи их, чтобы они не компилировались, <exclude> есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<taskdef classpath="ant-contrib.jar" resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
<for param="file">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${SRCDIR}">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" includes="${file}"
           destdir="${build}" failonerror="false"/>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Объявите файлсет и компилируйте файлы по одному. Для работы понадобится библиотека ant-contrib

Comment: Кажется, ant-contrib ещё потребуется?

Comment: @dnalchemist , спасибо... то что нужно!

Comment: @TagirValeev спасибо, поправил